# Digital Signing of XFA forms

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, livecycle, xfa

I'd like to sign PDF documents created in Adobe Livecycle (it is XFA form) programmatically.

I know about iText library for manipulating with PDFs, but I haven't found any example how to sign it yet.

Maybe its not supported yet. Do you know any other Java library which can do that? Or do you know a way how to sign it?

I know, my question is [similar to this opened question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030113/how-to-digitally-sign-pdf-files-with-xfa-forms-using-itext), but I don't need the use of iText.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a small example showing how to sign using XmlDSig:

```
PdfReader reader =new  PdfReader(src);
FileOutputStream os =new  FileOutputStream(dest);
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createXmlSignature(reader, os);
XmlSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getXmlSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setXmlLocator(new  XfaXmlLocator(stamper));
appearance.setXpathConstructor(new XfaXpathConstructor(XfaXpathConstructor.XdpPackage.Datasets));
ExternalSignature signature =new  PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm,"BC");
//use signXmlDSig or signXades
MakeXmlSignature.signXmlDSig(appearance, signature, chain);
```

You can also sign using XAdES, but then you won't be able to validate the signature in Adobe software because I don't think Adobe already supports XAdES (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Dear Bruno, thank you very much for your response! I tried it and it seems, I'm halfway there. When I open my "signed" document in Adobe Reader and click on panel "Signatures", I see there "Data Signatures" and my sign. But there is also an item "Unsigned Signature Fields" - root[0].containerpage[0].footer[0].SignatureField1[0] and my signature is missing here :(. I don't know, how to find this field and how to sign it. I have a XFA form created in Adobe Livecycle (from 3rd party). After my signature, the document must be the same as I sign it manualy. If it helps, I can send you my PDF doc.

Comment: Hi, I've found out that when a programmer uses iText and calls PdfSignatureAppearance#setVisibleSignature(), iText expects this field in AcroForm. But my signature field isn't there :-(. Do you know any other way how to set the path to the signature field?

Comment: Acrobat creates an AcroForm field when signing an XFA document and that this behavior isn't documented anywhere. For now, we've implemented XML signing as described in the specs. This means that we're technically able to sign the XFA so that Acrobat/Reader recognizes the signature as an "XFA signature". To find out if and how we can sign so the signature is completely "green" (e.g. no unsigned changes after signature), further investigation is needed. As this goes beyond what we can offer as free support (it costs time and resources and there is no spec), you won't get an answer here.