# Certify XFA document using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature, xfa, certify

I'm using iTextSharp 5.5.2 and I want to certify an XFA document with a digital certificate.
My code looks as follows:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
FileStream os = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create);
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createXmlSignature(reader, os);
XmlSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.XmlSignatureAppearance;
appearance.SetXmlLocator(new XfaXmlLocator(stamper));
appearance.SetXpathConstructor(new XfaXpathConstructor(XfaXpathConstructor.XdpPackage.Datasets)); // Optional Line
appearance.SetCertificate(myCert);
var pk = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(myCert.PrivateKey).Private;
IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1);
MakeXmlSignature.SignXmlDSig(appearance, pks, GenerateKeyInfo(myChain));
```

Unfortunately, when I open the PDF after certification, it pops up that the "verify operation failed."
If I comment out the optional line related to the XfaXpathConstructor, I get the banner message along the type of the PDF that says that "At least one data signature is invalid".

Either way, I am unable to open the Signature Panel and the PDF does not successfully certify... What am I missing?

Comment: I think you might get your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749485/digital-signing-of-xfa-forms